# Subdirectory in URL gets interpreted as GET Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, url, get

I have been fighting with this problem for a long time.

I only have this problem on the live server:

When I go to example.com?page=2&foo=bar and do a dump of $_GET, I get

```
array(2) { ["page"]=> string(1) "5" ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" }
```

as expected. However, when I am not on the root of the site

e.g. example.com/users?page=5&foo=bar i get this:

```
array(1) { ["/users"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I thought maybe it has to do with .htaccess, but I tried deleting everything there and still get the same results.

Comment: Laravel tinkers with the global variables. Use a request instance object or a facade instead.

Comment: Do you get the desired results if you do `dd(request()->get('page'), request()->get('foo'))`

Comment: Could you show us your routes file, please?